# jQuery and Javascript: offset.top() not responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to make offset.top() responsive?  If not, how could I make the animated div on scroll responsive when it touches the top of the browser?

In my fiddle, when you scroll down, the `div` correctly goes to the top but if you scrunch the screen heightwise, it doesn't act as intended anymore.
From my understanding, this is because the variable that the div is stored is being called once, but when I bind it to the scroll event, the div doesn't work as intended.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/j2yrumyg/8/

```js
$(function(){

var cheese= $('.ok').offset().top; //Define top of 'hey'

//
//Animates when it reaches red part of page
//
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= cheese  ) {
  
        $('.ok').addClass('top');

        $('.nice').hide().fadeIn().html('ok');
            $(".nice").animate({ 
            left:"0"
        }, 600);
        $('.nice').addClass('maybe');

    }
    else{
                $('.ok').removeClass('top');
                $('.nice').removeClass('maybe');
                $('.nice').html('Hey');


    }
});

//
//This part doesn't rely on scroll event and is in charge of changing hover on ".ok" div.
//

      $('.ok').hover(function(){
         if(!$(this).hasClass("top"))
           $(this).addClass('proj-hover');
         
              },function(){
                $(this).removeClass('proj-hover');
               
              });


//
//Animate on click
//
$('.ok').click(function(){
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= cheese  ) {

}
else{
    $("body, html").animate({ 
            scrollTop: $('.other').offset().top 
        }, 600);
     
}
});








});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body,html{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.div{
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  background:#6464FF;
}
.other{
  height:1000px;
  width:100%;
  background:#FF6161;
}
.ok{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-100px;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  transition:1s;
}

.top{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition:.7s;
      margin-left: 0px;
      width:100%;

}
.proj-hover{
  background:white;
  color:black;
}
.blue{
  background:blue;
}
.nice{
  transition:0s;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  
  <div class="ok">
  <p class="nice">Hey</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="other">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code just gets the `.top()` from element **.ok** at the begin. For it to work, you also should use something that won't change it's location, as the **.other** element.

Updated your code just here:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var cheese= $('.other').offset().top; //Define top of 'hey'
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= cheese  ) {
        ...
    }
});
```

**Update**
But if you want to get the position based on the element **.ok**, you will need to create a placeholder element for it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="div">
  <div class="placeholder">
    <div class="ok">
      <p class="nice">Hey</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="other"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ok,
.placeholder{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-100px;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  transition:1s;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var cheese= $('.placeholder').offset().top; //Define top of 'hey'
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= cheese  ) {
        ...
    }
});
```

[Fiddle with result](https://jsfiddle.net/j2yrumyg/13/)

Comment: Thanks that worked but was hoping for a more dynamic approach, imagine if both the blue div and red div were 100vh, then this approach would not work unfortunately.

Comment: With both setted to 100vh it works, as `$(window).scrollTop()` will be equal to `cheese`. This animation should be triggered when it reaches the desired height. What scenario are you looking for to achieve? [Fiddle with both been 100vh](https://jsfiddle.net/j2yrumyg/12/)

Comment: Ah, I see, that's pretty good but what if you really wanted to get the top of that div just out of curiosity?

Comment: Ok. Now I get what you mean. I will update my answer now.